# Storage consumption when installing boost libraries into a git repository

Tags: git, boost

I'm pushing at work to get official sign-off to install and use Boost libraries.  We recently adopted git, and I find that the default Boost installation uses 500MB for 24000 files.  Since git replicates the entire repository for each user (currently approx. 35), this adds up to a lot of NFS space usage, and it appears to affect git performance.  It doesn't appear that Boost is like, say, CPAN, which would allow us to install bits and pieces and would resolve dependencies.  It seems to be all or nothing.

I haven't much experience with either git or Boost, and I'm wondering how others have dealt with this.  Keep Boost out of git?  Carefully prune the Boost directory each time there's a new release?  Use a Boost installation manager whose existence I'm unaware of?

Thanks.

Comment: I typically include the boost distribution as a tarball in my repository, and logic in a Makefile to extract & build it

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you are saying it sounds like it is possible for you guys to use a `.gitignore` file to solve your problem. A `.gitignore` file would let you ignore the parts of your boost library that are not changing. You can create a `.gitignore` file in unix as followed:

```
touch .gitignore
# or 
nano .gitignore
```

You'll want to make sure that your `.gitignore` file is at the top of your project directory up there with your `.git` folder. Once you have a `.gitignore` file, you can put file and directory paths that you do not want git to track in there like so:

```
# This is the titan project gitignore file

# this section includes general files that should be ignored
*.txt
.project
*.csv

# these are general places to ignore in this project
.settings/
# this would let you ignore a directory from boost
boost/
```

If everyone's version of boost is the same and you guys are not editting it, then it sounds like you can safely `.gitignore` it.

Here is a link to github's documentation on the subject:
https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files